# How are skill increases calculated?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-ii-daggerfall

If you use a skill enough times, then that skill increases the next time that you rest, assuming you've waited long enough since your last skill increase.

What I want to know is exactly how the number of skill uses per skill increase is calculated.

Unlike later Elder Scrolls games, there's no progress bar on each skill letting you know how much you need to wait to get another skill up. When I'm training up a skill, I'd like to know how far along I am before my next skill up, and how many checks I need to make before I can safely rest and gain another skill level.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no one can give you a definitive answer here, because the level up speed of skills depends on several factors

1) How high the skill is, every 15 points (15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90) the number of skillups increases, see [uesp wiki](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Daggerfall:Leveling_and_Skills), unknown how big the effect is or if it exists.

2) The position of the skill advancement dagger for your class (between 0.3 and 3.0x)

3) Whether the skill is primary, major, minor or misc for your class (the former levelling faster) (see game manual), unknown how big the effect is or if it exists.

4) The value of the skills governing attribute. E.g. climbings governing attribute is strength. The stronger you are, the faster you can level climbing. (see game manual), unknown how big the effect is or if it exists.

5) The skill itself, each skill follows a different leveling formula (e.g. running is pretty much permanently increased slowly, while the language skills are only checked, when you talk to that creature and failure or success also yield different skill up results)

Testing this is also very hard compared to later TES games

1) Daggerfall is older and far buggier than any modern TES.

2) Daggerfall doesn't display skill exp and you only get skill ups while resting

3) Unlike later TES games, Daggerfall has no mod tools, which allow you to read out the raw values for each skill.

To get those numbers for a later TES merely requires you to read them in the construction kit. To get those numbers in Daggerfall requires meticulous controlled testing with tons of scenarios.

E.g. to find numbers for running, you have to run for one minute, rest, check, whether you get a skill up. If not, reload and run a little longer, if yes, reload and run a little less. Repeat until you find the exact time needed to level up. And repeat this test for different values of speed and running as primary/major/minor/misc skill to determine the influence of those elements.

All those factors make it impossible to give any definitive answer to your question.

Comment: "It depends on several factors" isn't a good reason to say there's no definitive answer. (This)[http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Increasing_Skills] is an example from Oblivion, which includes many factors in its analysis. In addition, it would be helpful if you could cite your sources for 1, 3, and 4. I accept that the skill advancement dagger and skill check frequency affect skill increases, but I haven't seen any information claiming the other three points before, and I'd like to know where you found it.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl Seriously? You compare it to Oblivion? You do realize Daggerfall is 10 years older? And Daggerfall doesn't display skill exp? And Daggerfall has no mod tools, which allow you to read out the raw values for each skill? And Daggerfall is far buggier than any other TES game? And you only get skill ups while resting? To get those numbers for Oblivion merely requires you to read them in the construction kit. to get those number in Daggerfall requires meticulous controlled testing with tons of scenarios. cont...

Comment: .. cont In truth, it's not even clear, how and even if 1, 3, 4 affect the levelling speed of skills. It's just so hard test, especially skills like languages. Or running for that matter. Do you want people to spend hours running, determining the exact time required for a skill up and repeat that with different combinations of attributes to determine a difference? Besides, where does the Oblivion table include "many factors"? There is a number of exp required and an exp per action, which yields a number of actions required. This is multiplied by 0.75, 0.6 or 0.45. That's it. It's two factors.

Comment: Comments are used to request clarification... if you don't like an answer, or if you think an answer is inadequate, the solution is to post an answer of your own.

Comment: @Dulkan I think all those points you make in your comments are valid, and this answer would be improved if you included them there. Explaining _why_ it's "impossible to give any definitive answer" would definitely make this answer better. I've upvoted now that you've added citations for your claims.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl I implemented my comments into the other.